# Visa requirement at KLIA2 as a transit point with separate PNR

Tags: layovers, transit-visas, kul, airasia

I am an Indian citizen wanting to visit Malaysia and Singapore with my family at the end of October 2017, for tourism.

I am applying for eNTRI (single entry visa for Indian Citizens) for Malaysia and for a normal visa for Singapore (single or multiple as the case may be).

While returning to India from Singapore, I have a connecting Air Asia flight at KLIA2 with approximately 2 hours' layover.

Both SIN–KUL and KUL-HYD are Air Asia flights departing from the same terminal, KLIA2, but having a separate PNR number.

We are carrying only hand baggage (cabin baggage). Also we will be doing web check-in for the KUL-HYD leg, and we will have our printed boarding passes ready for the same, in advance.

In the above scenario, do we need to go through Malaysian immigration formalities again at KLIA2 while returning from Singapore?

If yes, do we need a transit visa or another type of visa, even if we do not wish to leave the transit hall or airport terminal within that 2 hour period?

Answer (score 4):

In your case, you don't need to clear immigration at KLIA2.
I have done this several times, not to India but other countries where I do not need a visa. If your KUL-HYD boarding pass does not need Document Check then you are good to go. Just follow the transit direction, clear security and make your way to the departure gate.
Hope this help.